# can't create folder with puppet

Tags: file, puppet, manifest

I am running a `puppet` manifest to create a directory. So I put this in  `site.pp` file

```
node 'master0', 'agent1', 'agent2' {
        include some_class
        file{'/home/my_user/scripts':
                ensure => 'directory'
        }
}
```

The username is the same on the different nodes. I get the `scripts` folder created in `master0` but not on the agent nodes. I have no error output, someone can explain ?

Comment: Verbose output on the nodes?

Comment: Does `/home/my_user` already exist on all the machines?  (Or do you have a separate `File` resource to manage it?)

Comment: can you check running puppet in agent with `--debug` tag so that we can get detailed information regarding this

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes the `/home/my_user` folder exists on every node

Comment: @Thirumoorthi I get a successful output - with no single error

Answer (score 1):

I got it, my issue has nothing to do with the manifest structure which is fine. I had a firewall issue and the agents could not connect to the master.